# How can i do geocoding in javascript to get lat and long?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is how i am trying, but i am not getting any response. What could be wrong ?

API used:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=***&sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>



function initialize() {
     var addrLookup = 'San Diego , CA   92101';
     var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var geoRequest = { address: addrLookup };
     geoCoder.geocode(geoRequest,function(results,status){
        window.alert("response");
        console.log(status);
     });
}
```

Comment: That code works for me (well it fails in IE because console is not defined, but it says "response" before generating that error, and if I comment it out, it works with no errors).  Are you including the API?

Comment: I have just edited my question. Is it the right way to include the api ? or am i supposed to do something else too ?

Comment: You are including the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) which was deprecated on May 19, 2010.  Probably should use the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (the documentation shows how to include the API), and read the terms of use, geocoding without using the results on a Google Maps API map is prohibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modify your script:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
              var addrLookup = 'San Diego , CA   92101';
              var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              var geoRequest = { address: addrLookup };
              geoCoder.geocode(geoRequest,function(results,status){

                  console.log('latitude: ',results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                  console.log('longitude: ',results[0].geometry.location.lng());
              });
           }
    </script>

    <body onload="initialize()">


</body></html>
```